# convert jquery script for checkboxes to work with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I found this very usefull script called BlueToggleButton on jqueryscript.net [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Turn-Checkboxes-Into-Toggle-Buttons-BlueToggleButton.html)

Basically it converts checkboxes to customized buttons of your choice. It works great, though it would be ever greater if there would be a way to do the same for radio buttons. I'm totally not into jQuery and Javascript, so I don't really know where to start. I tried to replace the "checkbox" strings inside the code with "radio" but that didn't seem to do the trick.

The script looks like this. It is connected to a css-file where you can style your buttons and some images to use inside the buttons.

```
$(function ($) {
$.widget("toggle.toggleButton", {
    options : {
        text : "Toggle",
        toggleOnColor : "green",
        onTitle : "On",
        offTitle : "Off",
        onImg: "toggleON.png",
        offImg: "toggleOFF.png",
        change : null
    },

    _create : function() {
        var id = this.element.attr("id");
        var checkBoxStyle = this.element.attr("style");

        this.element.css({
            "display" : "none"
        });

        this.checkboxButton = $("<label>", {
            text : this.options.text,
            "class" : "toggleButton",
            "for" : id,
            "style" : checkBoxStyle
        });

        this.element.after(this.checkboxButton);

        if (this.element.is(":checked")) {
            this.element
                .next("label").css({ "background" : this.options.toggleOnColor, "color" : "white" })
                .prop({ "title" : this.options.onTitle })
                .prepend('<span class="toggle-img" style="background:url(' + this.options.onImg + '); background-position:center;" />');

        } else {
            this.element
                .next("label").css({ "background" : "", "color" : "grey" })
                .prop({ "title" : this.options.offTitle })
                .prepend('<span class="toggle-img" style="background:url(' + this.options.offImg + '); background-position:center;" />');

        };

        this._on(this.element, {
            "change" : function(event) {
                if (this.element.is(":checked")) {
                    this.element
                        .next("label").css({ "background" : this.options.toggleOnColor, "color" : "white" })
                        .prop({ "title" : this.options.onTitle })
                        .find(".toggle-img")
                        .css({"background" : "url(" + this.options.onImg + ")" });
                } else {
                    this.element
                        .next("label").css({ "background" : "", "color" : "grey" })
                        .prop({ "title" : this.options.offTitle })
                        .find(".toggle-img")
                        .css({"background" : "url(" + this.options.offImg + ")" });
                };
            }
        });
    }
});
}(jQuery));
```

edit: this is the html that's used with it:

```
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-button">
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle-button2">

    <script>
        $("#toggle-button").toggleButton({text : "Checked button"});
        $("#toggle-button2").toggleButton({text : "Un-checked button"});
    </script>
```

Any ideas? I tried to get in contact with the creator but didn't get a response. Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: the existing script is converting checkboxes to buttons. I want the script to do the same for radio buttons, so that radio buttons are likewise converted to buttons. I tried to alter the code by replacing the "checkbox" strings with "radio" but that doesn't work, it just doesn't do anything. Should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can solve it with pure CSS. See this code:

```css
input
{
  display: none;
}
.notchecked,
.checked {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

input:checked + .label-wrapper .checked {
  display: block;
}

input:not(:checked) + .label-wrapper .notchecked {
  display: block;
}

.label-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
}

input:checked + .label-wrapper {
  background-color: green;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  curosr: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='radiogroup' id='first-radio' checked>
<div class='label-wrapper'>
  <label for='first-radio'> </label>
  <span class='checked'>Checked</span>
  <span class='notchecked'>Not Checked</span>
</div>
<input type='radio' name='radiogroup' id='second-radio'>

<div class='label-wrapper'>
  <label for='second-radio'></label>
  <span class='checked'>Checked</span>
  <span class='notchecked'>Not Checked</span>
</div>

<input type='radio' name='radiogroup' id='third-radio'>
<div class='label-wrapper'>
  <label for='third-radio'></label>
  <span class='checked'>Checked</span>
  <span class='notchecked'>Not Checked</span>
</div>
```

and here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9hcmrd7q/1/

Comment: this is awesome! Thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry man, I accidentally clicked the aecond answer, since I came on the bottom of the page. I had to wait 22 hours to grant the points and didnt notice someone else had poates a similar answer and took that answer mistakenly as yours. If an admin could fix this, please do. I wanted to grant the bounty to kalimah apps.

Comment: thanks Roddeh. I flagged your comment for moderation attention.

Comment: Unfortunately, points can not be reassigned. This a reference for future readers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140290/bounty-awarded-to-a-different-answer-by-mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure CSS, without any JS at all, with a minimum of additional HTML markup. This solution works equally as well for radio buttons and checkboxes.

1. Ensure each "checkable" (`checkbox` or `radio`) `input` has an adjacent `label`.
2. Add the class `input__checkable--button` to both the `input` and the `label`

   ```
   <input type="radio" class="input__checkable--button" name="radioButtons" id="radioButtons_1">
   <label for="radioButtons_1" class="label__checkable--button">First Radio Button</label>
   ```
3. Add some CSS

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kevindb/4waydtoa/
Stack Snippet:

```css
.label__checkable--button {
  float: left;
  min-width: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: .5em;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Prevent text in buttons from being selected/highlighted */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.input__checkable--button {
  display: none;
}
.input__checkable--button:checked + .label__checkable--button {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #1C4882;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioButtons" id="radioButtons_1" value="1" class="input__checkable--button">
<label for="radioButtons_1" class="label__checkable--button">First Radio Button</label>

<input type="radio" name="radioButtons" id="radioButtons_2" value="2" class="input__checkable--button">
<label for="radioButtons_2" class="label__checkable--button">Second Radio Button</label>

<br><br><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkButtons" id="checkButtons_1" value="1" class="input__checkable--button">
<label for="checkButtons_1" class="label__checkable--button">First Checkbox Button</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkButtons" id="checkButtons_2" value="2" class="input__checkable--button">
<label for="checkButtons_2" class="label__checkable--button">Second Checkbox Button</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the following line in your html：

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```